# How to determine electrical energy and the convert it to heat?

Tags: heat, electrical, energy

I've been stuck on a problem for quite some time now. I really cannot get my head around it. It's been a while for me, and I just recently been taking up a class again in electrical 
engineering. I've really been reading since yesterday however I don't know if I should start by calculating the power (the thing that's messing with my brain is that there is two current sources)

Could someone be so kind and lead me into the right direction on this problem?

[image]

Comment: Draw the currents on a piece of paper - the answer's right there in front of you.

Answer (score 3):

You don't start by calculating the power so much as you start by calculating the current (Either nodal analyis with KCL or mesh analysis with KVL will work). You are going to need to find the current in both loops and calculate the power for each resistor individually using the calculated currents.

\$P = I^2R\$ which is Watts. Watts is Joules per second. You just want Joules and you know you have 1 hour (3600s) Can you take it from there?

**Hint:** You have two current sources. They determine the current flowing in their branch, and you just so happen to need the current in each loop. So you could do it by inspection without KVL or KCL if you know what you are looking for. The problem is actually much simpler than if it were two voltage sources.  That said, you won't learn too much by doing it by inspection since it won't help you solve these circuits in general.

Comment: Should I combine the resistors to a total and also combine the current sources? (sorry if my english is a little bit weird, swedish is my first language)

Comment: @Vetenskap Your English is fine. I would not notice a difference if you did not point it out. You cannot combine resistors or current sources because there are no neat parallel or series combination of either in this circuit.

Comment: I will give it a try and see if I can figure it out. Thank you for now! :)

Comment: @Vetenskap Hint: You have two current sources. They determine the current flowing in their branch, and you just so happen to need the current in each loop. So you could do it by inspection without KVL or KCL if you know what you are looking for. The problem is actually much simpler than if it were two voltage sources.

Comment: Is it correct if for the first resistor (20kohm), I calculate P = (0.1)^2 * 20000 = 200 W and for the other resistor (10kohm) P = (0.3)^2 * 10000 = 900 W? If that is correct I'm stuck on the 500 ohm resistor, how I should consider it?

Comment: @Vetenskap Those are correct. At the center node between all resistors, you know the current from each current source cannot go backwards through the other current source. That's because they are current sources (this would not be true of voltage sources). So where must the current flow when they crash up against each other? You could do this by intuition, or you could use nodal analysis and KCL (and knowing how to do this will be more helpful in the future than just by intuition).

Comment: I guess I should think of it like I1 + I2 = I3, which gives me 100mA + 300 mA = 400 mA..?

Comment: @Vetenskap Yes. You should try this problem against with two voltage sources instead afterwards. That will force you to not rely on intuition so much and more on equations which will be more helplful in general.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. So now that I have the power for each of the resistors, I get the combined power to 1180 W. However when I take P = Joules / seconds I get 1180 * 3600 = 4.2 MJ, though the correct answer is 1.15 MJ. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Vetenskap You aren't doing anything wrong from what I can see. I have no idea where 1.15MJ is coming from.

Comment: Oh okay, I've been sitting the last 15 min and couldn't find what I did wrong. Seems like the answer on the sheet my professor gave us may be wrong on this particular problem. Thank you for your help. I will try with voltage sources too, like you suggested. :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try to answer the following questions:

1. What is the current through the 20 kΩ resistor?
2. What is the current through the 10 kΩ resistor?
3. What is the current through the 500 Ω resistor?

Remember:
$$P = I^2 R.$$